# How to change typescript to javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This code is in typescript and I want to write it in javascript

```
const Home = (props: { name: string }) => {
    return ( <div> {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'You are not logged in'} </div> );
};
```

How to change this part `(props: { name: string })` into javascript?

Comment: Can you show us more context? Is that an argument list for a function? (in which case it's just `(props)` without the type declaration)

Comment: const Home = (props: { name: string }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'You are not logged in'}
        </div>
    );
};

Comment: I don't know why vaira's answer was downvoted and deleted: it looked OK to me. Since this is a lambda you don't need the brackets around the args list, just `props =>`, but otherwise I couldn't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: You could just ask Typescript to [do it for you](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAEiAtgUxgXhgCgA4CcTYQBcMA3jGAIYonS4CWYA5jAL4CU6AfGQFAwCYuZFACuuMFhgAeACb0Abj1J4CEAHRUUMAPwwA5HHoGYAahirCm6qhL6AmiFExKwiiFgAbEEybJZMIz6rDIA9PJKMOwA3LyssUA). Turning typescript into javascript is what the compiler is really good at.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the parameter's type (`(props: { name: string })` => `(props)`):

```js
const Home = (props) => {
    return ( <div> {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'You are not logged in'} </div> );
};
```

And since there is only one argument (`props`), you can also write it this way:

```js
const Home = props => {
    return ( <div> {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'You are not logged in'} </div> );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TS playground to convert TypeScript to JavaScript.

Check JSX "preserve" option to keep JSX if any

Example : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAEiAtgUxgXhgCgA4CcTYQBcMA3jGAIYonS4CWYA5jAL4CU6AfGQLABQMITFzIoAV1xgsMADwATegDcepPAQgA6KihgB+GAHI49IzADUMdYW3VUJQwE0Q4mJVEUQsADYgmTZHkYRkNWOQB6RRUYdgBuAVZYoA

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not pure typescript but typescript with JSX.  So you can do

```
tsc --jsx preserve input.tsx
```

And you'll get

```
var Home = function (props) {
    return (<div> {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'You are not logged in'} </div>);
};
```

If you do

```
tsc --jsx preserve --target es6 input.tsx
```

You get

```
const Home = (props) => {
    return (<div> {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'You are not logged in'} </div>);
};
```

---

I'm guessing what you really wanted to ask is you were learning React and wanted to try out a hello world example but only had a js environment set up.  You can go to CodePen or similar websites to [try our your code snippets](https://codepen.io/stackshare/pen/WNOwLbY) and don't worry too much about ts or js yet.